# Unable to resolve promise that returns data from api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm using https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce to fetch some data, but I'm not able to transfer what it receives to the modules that imports this function.

**apisause-get.js**

```
  1 import {create} from 'apisauce'
  2
  3 const api = create({
  4   baseURL: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com',
  5 })
  6
  7 export default api
  8   .get('/stabenfeldt/14db8a93d8bffd5258e29c03e2dfe234/raw/207c7facfa8ad5c1cce20ed08d954dad4a8ee75e/token.json')
  9   .then((response) => response.data)
 10   //.then(console.log)  // outputs correct data here
 11
```

**consumer.js**

```
  1 import getter from './apisause-get.js';
  2
  3 let result = getter();
  4
  5 console.log('==================');
  6 console.log('we got result: ', result);  // I'm not getting the result from the api.
```

`babel-node consumer.js` does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result
getter().then(res=> result = res)
```

a typical Asynchronous problem. I prefer to use async that supported in ES7

```
let getData = async () => {
   result = await getter()
}
getData()
```

Comment: Hi, I added your last code block to consumer.js, but that doesn't work. `we got result:  undefined`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

**consumer.js**

```
import getter from './apisause-get';

let result;

getter.then( (result) => {
  console.log('==================');
  console.log('we got result: ', result);  // Works! :)
})
```

Comment: No need to declare `let result` in the module scope